# Matchstick puzzle next version

Tags: matches

Here is a matchstick equation which is obviously wrong.

18019=1

Make the equation correct by moving "fewest" matchsticks (my solution involves 3 moves).

You may use numbers, letters, Roman Numerals but only as below

1 matchstick used for - or / (subtract or divide)

2 Matchsticks used for I and 1  AND +, =, X (multiply)

3 for L,T,Y and 7

4 for C,F,J,K,V,X,Z AND 4

5 for E,H,P,S,U and 2,3,5

6 for A,D,G,M,N,O,R,W and 0,6,9

7 for B,Q and 8

You can use spaces between numbers to insert only one thing like function or number. **

**NO INEQUALITY OR > OR < allowed**
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution is by 1 shift only. (n_palum says it is one shift only due to division being a single match movement. I concur with him on that.)

> [image]

Comment: I'd say that's just 1 shift since / counts as 1 according to the rules. Nice find!

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is allowed, but it does not look to be prohibited.

1 move.

> from the first 1, move the top matchstick, below the second one and you get
>  $1^{8019} = 1$ which is true

Comment: That's a clever solution!

Comment: Technically, that gives $1^{8019=1}$

Comment: Why you have to ruin it for me? :) You are kind of right. I can move 2 more the top stick from the = sign lower and the top stick from the 1 after the = sign to make it look ok. Soe I'm still in the allowed margin of 3 moves.

Answer (score 5):

4 sticks -

> $100 - 0 = C$
>  [image]
>
>  Moved 4 sticks.

Answer (score 5):

2 shifts:

> 10 / 010 = 1
>  (Read in decimal, not octal)
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple as 1×1. Reverse and assume as

> 6<sup>1×0×8×1</sup> or as 6<sup>1×0×81</sup>.
>
>  1^8019 works too.
>
>  0 shifts as assuming exponentiation.